# Can VisualStudio 2013 be installed on Windows Vista?

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I already tried to install it but it show me a message box and does not let me install it, is there any version for windows vista?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Visual Studio 2012, Microsoft has limited compatibility to Windows 7 or higher. If you want to run Visual Studio on a Vista operating system, you will need Visual Studio 2010 or 2008. Here's a link to the 2010 express edition: http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_4